# Angularjs ng-model - convert string to number

Tags: angularjs

I see a blank drop down, which I suspect is due to an additional option that gets injected. If I am able to remove this additional option generated, I think, my problem will be solved.

Auto-injected Option:

```
<option value="? number:1 ?" selected="selected"></option>
```

My View:

```
<select id="myValue"
    ng-model="myObject.value"
    ng-change="foo()">
    <option value="0"
        localize="MyValue0"
        ng-selected="myObject.value === 0"></option>
    <option value="1"
        localize="MyValue1"
        ng-selected="myObject.value === 1"></option>    
</select>
```

How can I conver myObject.value to number? I have tried ng-Model = "parseInt(myObject.value)" and ng-model = "myObject.value | number". Both throw a nonassignable element error. I am using Angularjs 1.6 and moving away from directives, so creating angular.directive function may not be an option

Comment: change it inside `foo()`, e.g. `$scope.myObject.value = Number($scope.myObject.value)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's Angular best practice to use the ngOptions directive, documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Also, regarding the first option being `<option value="? number:1 ?" selected="selected"></option>`, I suspect that's because the initial value of myObject.value doesn't match any of the possible options values.

Try this:

```
<select id="myValue" ng-model="myObject.value" ng-change="foo()"
        ng-options="item for item in options">
    <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Placeholder</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/1vywt6kn/1/) showing that myObject.value is a number.

Updated JSFiddle to showcase the dropdown without a placeholder.

Comment: I updated ng-options but I do not want to see the Placeholder. Only the ones in options should be displayed. Is it possible to convert value in ng-model to a string type? My underlying values are enums

Comment: I also explicitly converted value to Number by using Number(value) before assigning it to myObject, That did not help either.

Comment: I've updated the answer (the jsfiddle) to show how you could implement the dropdown without a placeholder.

Regarding underlying values, ENUMs or not, it shouldn't make a difference as JavaScript will only parse them as String or Number.

I'm not sure I understand your issue anymore, could you please expand?

Comment: They have the same url :)

Comment: Oups, fixed that :)

Comment: Embedded link got removed :)

Comment: I've replaced the old one with a single new one, since it was an update, not something new.
https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/1vywt6kn/1/